# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '(CLLocationCoordinate2D, String, UIColor) -> UIView'?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I am getting:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '(CLLocationCoordinate2D, String, UIColor) -> UIView'

on the following line:

```
 guard let popup = self.popupFunc else {return}
```

This is a common error but I just cant seem to see why it gives me the error? When I remove the conditional binding here then I just get a bunch of errors in other parts of teh function in which it lies.

```
    var popup : UIView?
```

above is how it is declared. It is declared in another VC which is extended so that I can add MGLDelagate methods and that is where the following function is:

```
    func showPopup(_ shouldShow: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    guard let popup = self.popupFunc else {return}

    if shouldShow {
        view.addSubview(popup)
    }

    let alpha: CGFloat = (shouldShow ? 1 : 0)

    let animation = {
        popup.alpha = alpha
    }

    let completion = { (_: Bool) in
        if !shouldShow {
            popup.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    if animated {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: animation, completion: completion)
    } else {
        animation()
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

*I am trying to attain the functionality* [**here**](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/clustering/).

Comment: Isn’t `popupFunc` function which you have to call with certain parameters?

Comment: That's what I would think but as mapbox shows that does not need to be the case. @RobertDresler

Comment: 'guard' condition is always true, body is unreachable @LeoDabus When I do you comment, also I get a bunch of other erros I would get when I get rid of teh conditional binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Func" is incorrect here:

```
guard let popup = self.popupFunc else {return}
```

From the error and the rest of your discussion and code, you seem to have meant:

```
guard let popup = self.popup else {return}
```

It's not clear what `popupFunc` is, though. It's defined, you just don't list it here. Perhaps you accidentally allowed autocomplete to pick the wrong property?